# sqlite insert with c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-insert

i am testing my sqlite local server with c#, I have the connection and query setup without problem. I tried to copy the query to sqlite and it runs without problem. However, when I run it in my program, nothing insert into the db. Wondering what the problem is.

I have set the db build action to Content, and the copy to output directory options to copy if newer

```
private void insertIntoDB(string query)
{
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=.\\VHTDatabase.db"))
    {
        using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            Console.WriteLine(query);
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is targeting the database inside your bin/Debug folder, not the database inside your project, because that is where the code is being executed from.

Comment: @JessedeWit i have already add the db into the project tho

Comment: Try a full path to the database instead of a relative path in your connectionstring and try again.

Comment: Search your ahrd disk for all occurrences of `VHTDatabase.db` and look in each one; you'll find your data somewhere, not in the DB youre looking in right now

Answer (score 0):

Try a full path to your database in your Connectionstring

Then maybe try to add the CommandText before you open the Connection.

i mean:

```
cmd.CommandText = query;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Does your database give you informations with SELECT?
Maybe you need to reconfigure the User of the Database and give him rights to write, change and delete.

If nothing helps, then you can check, if it gives you an error.

```
try
{
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```